# как работать с бд в Telegram bot на python

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

я использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotapi. я не могу добавить по команде баланс и ид помгите вот код как я это пытаюсь сделать
'''

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import Message
from telebot import types
import sqlite3 as sql
import random 




bot = telebot.TeleBot('1027108067:AAE7OHXI4lQ0ALPQr7s5ujkMAYNiuBxTWSE')


conn = sql.connect("as.sqlite3", check_same_thread=False)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE users (id int AUTO_INCREMENT, tg_id int, name TEXT, balance int DEFAUTLT, PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (tg_id))')


cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY name LIMIT 1")

results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - {1.first_name} ".format(message.from_user,bot.get_me())),
    cursor.execute("insert into users (name) values ('ss') ")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text','document'])
def hello(message):
    if message.text == "Пр":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, я бот . Напиши 'Команды' ")
        cursor.execute("insert into users (balance) values ('1000') ")
    elif message.text == 'вв':
        a = str(random.randint(1,9))
        b = str(random.randint(1,9))
        c = str(random.randint(1,9))



        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{a}{b}{c}')

        if a == b and b == c and c == a:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'вы выйграли куш')

        elif a == b and b==c and a==c:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'удачно')

        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неудачно')




bot.polling(none_stop=True)
'''
```

Comment: А что не получается? Происходит ошибка? Или ничего не добавляется? Кст, вы знаете что при работе с базой нужно вызывать `.commit()`, чтобы изменения были сохранены в базе либо работать через оператор `with`, чтобы тот автоматически вызывал коммит?

Comment: узнал в тот же день